# Kerberos Exception while connecting to Cloudera Impala via JDBC

Tags: java, hadoop, user-defined-functions, kerberos, impala

I try to connect to to Impala using JDBC and Kerberos authentication in Java. I have 2 classes, the first creates a connections using `UserGroupInformation` and JDBC. This class have the following code

```
static final String JDBC_IMPALA_URL = "jdbc:impala://cdwork05-zzz.com:21050;"
+ "AuthMech=1;KrbRealm=XXX.COM;KrbHostFQDN=cdwork05-zzz.com;"
+ "KrbServiceName=impala;"
+ "SSL=1;AllowSelfSignedCerts=1;";  
static final String JDBC_DRIVER_IMPALA ="com.cloudera.impala.jdbc41.Driver"; 

public Connection crearConexion2() throws ClassNotFoundException, SQLException {
    Class.forName(JDBC_DRIVER_IMPALA);
    con = DriverManager.getConnection(JDBC_IMPALA_URL);
    return con;

}

public UserGroupInformation autenticarUsuario() throws IOException {
    Configuration conf = new Configuration();
    conf.set("hadoop.security.authentication", "Kerberos");
    UserGroupInformation.setConfiguration(conf);
    UserGroupInformation.loginUserFromKeytab( "User@XXX.COM", "/etc/security/keytabs/User.keytab");     
    return UserGroupInformation.getLoginUser();
}
```

The second class calls methods from the connection class, this class have the following code:

```
public class func_traer extends UDF{

    connections connectionsutls;
    Statement stmt;

    public String  evaluate(String fecha) {
        String tb="";
        String regs="";

        connectionsutls = new connections();
        try {
            UserGroupInformation ugi = connectionsutls.autenticarUsuario();
            Connection con = (Connection) ugi.doAs(new PrivilegedExceptionAction<Object>() {
                public Object run() {
                    Connection tcon = null;
                    try {
                        tcon = connectionsutls.crearConexion2();
                    }catch (Exception e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                    return tcon;
                }
            }
            );

            try {
                stmt = con.createStatement();
                try {
                    String query1= "select table_name,historic_registers " + 
                            "from statistics.incremental_statistics " + 
                            "where table_name like 'simon.a2000160' " + 
                            "and date_incremental like '"+fecha+"'" + 
                            ";";
                    ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery(query1);
                    while(rs.next()) {
                        tb = rs.getString("table_name");
                        regs = rs.getString("historic_registers");
                    }
                    connectionsutls.cerrarConexion(stmt);               

                    return "la tabla "+tb+" tiene  "+regs+" registros";
                }catch (Exception e) {
                    return "no se ejecuto debido a :"+e;
                }
            }catch (Exception e) {
                return "no se creo el statement "+e;
            }

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return "no se pudo autenticar "+e;
        }

    }

}
```

When I run this I get the exception:

```
    org.apache.hadoop.security.KerberosAuthException: Login failure for user: XXXX from keytab /etc/security/keytabs/XXXX.keytab javax.security.auth.login.LoginException: Pre-authentication information was invalid (24)
        at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.loginUserFromKeytab(UserGroupInformation.java:1134)
        at woombat.connections.autenticarUsuario(connections.java:47)
        at woombat.func_traer.evaluate(func_traer.java:30)
        at woombat.test.main(test.java:10)
    Caused by: javax.security.auth.login.LoginException: Pre-authentication information was invalid (24)
        at com.sun.security.auth.module.Krb5LoginModule.attemptAuthentication(Krb5LoginModule.java:804)
        at com.sun.security.auth.module.Krb5LoginModule.login(Krb5LoginModule.java:617)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at javax.security.auth.login.LoginContext.invoke(LoginContext.java:755)
        at javax.security.auth.login.LoginContext.access$000(LoginContext.java:195)
        at javax.security.auth.login.LoginContext$4.run(LoginContext.java:682)
        at javax.security.auth.login.LoginContext$4.run(LoginContext.java:680)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at javax.security.auth.login.LoginContext.invokePriv(LoginContext.java:680)
        at javax.security.auth.login.LoginContext.login(LoginContext.java:587)
        at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.loginUserFromKeytab(UserGroupInformation.java:1125)
        ... 3 more
    Caused by: KrbException: Pre-authentication information was invalid (24)
        at sun.security.krb5.KrbAsRep.<init>(KrbAsRep.java:76)
        at sun.security.krb5.KrbAsReqBuilder.send(KrbAsReqBuilder.java:316)
        at sun.security.krb5.KrbAsReqBuilder.action(KrbAsReqBuilder.java:361)
        at com.sun.security.auth.module.Krb5LoginModule.attemptAuthentication(Krb5LoginModule.java:776)
        ... 16 more
    Caused by: KrbException: Identifier doesn't match expected value (906)
        at sun.security.krb5.internal.KDCRep.init(KDCRep.java:140)
        at sun.security.krb5.internal.ASRep.init(ASRep.java:64)
        at sun.security.krb5.internal.ASRep.<init>(ASRep.java:59)
        at sun.security.krb5.KrbAsRep.<init>(KrbAsRep.java:60)
        ... 19 more
```

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: I assume you know who user 'XXXX' is, and have some administrative control over it, as it relates to this message:  'Login failure for user: XXXX from keytab /etc/security/keytabs/XXXX.keytab'

Comment: yes i know that is the user, when i use the keytab in console i can kinit but i can use in the java code i can't

Comment: You can kinit you said - that indicates success.  Let's confirm - post the kinit output here.

Comment: Make sure your command-line and java app use the same `krb5.conf` file. The error in KDCReply hints you're in the wrong domain.

Comment: The line "UserGroupInformation.loginUserFromKeytab( "User@XXX.COM", "/etc/security/keytabs/User.keytab");" looks suspicious to me.
Your keytab must contain keys corresponding to "User@XXX.COM". While in exception, it says "XXXX.keytab".
Have you verified that you are not confusing between two keytab files?